# Is there any API to get list of states for a country?

Tags: api, google-api

I wanted to get a list of all the states in a country using an API. I have tried Geonames.org also but it doesn't provide a list of states.

E.g. : I want to check states of India - Uttar Pradesh, Maharastra, etc.

Comment: You'd have to define what you count as a "state" first. Territories? Autonomous regions? Would the different parts of the UK count? How about the Swiss cantons? France's administrative regions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext) to extract the wikitext from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States_and_union_territories_of_India)

To extract wikitext: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&contentmodel=wikitext&page=States_and_union_territories_of_India&prop=wikitext&format=json

An example using [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) to extract with wikitext :

```python
import requests
import wikitextparser as wtp

r = requests.get(
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
        params = {
                'action': 'parse',
                'page': 'States_and_union_territories_of_India',
                'contentmodel': 'wikitext',
                'prop': 'wikitext',
                'format': 'json'
        }
)

data = wtp.parse(r.json()['parse']['wikitext']['*'])

print([
    wtp.parse(t[0]).wikilinks[0].target
    for t in data.tables[0].data()
    if t[0] != 'State'
])
```